# Unable to submit form with POST

Tags: html, forms, iis

Here is the code to my site:

http://pastebin.com/jVk0aPW4

When I try to submit the page, it does nothing. This is the first time time I've tried to submit on this webserver. The network admin assures that POST and GET are explicitly enabled.

Is my HTML malformed? Or do I need to dig deeper on the server side?

Comment: `<li class="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: selected in <b>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newpachamber.org\include\header.php</b> on line <b>45</b>
<br />">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested form, which will cause your form to explode (proper technical jargon).

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Now I'm getting a 405 error. Time to get the admin involved.